# Is Slowloris traceable?

Tags: ip, denial-of-service

When someone launches a [slowloris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris_(computer_security)) attack on a website, could that attack be traced via IP? Could someone feasibly locate the IP of the person that launches said attack?

Comment: The short answer is "yes". Because it is not a DDoS, it's a single attacker DoS. The logs will simply show lots of connections from a single IP...

Comment: I'm closing this because it's not clear what you are asking. Ultimately, anything done over an IP network is traceable by IP. Can you clarify or expand on your question?